# How to implement a command to get a table cell in Cypress?

Tags: cypress, cypress-custom-commands

I want to create a command with this interface:

```js
cy.getTableCell({ column: 'Name', row: 42 }).contains('Douglas Adams')
```

Where `getTableCell` would return the table cell (`td`) corresponding to the 42-th row of the table on the column `'Name'`. I came up with this implementation:

```js
type GetTableCellParams = {
  columnName: string;
  rowIndex: number;
};

Cypress.Commands.add(
  'getTableCell',
  ({ columnName, rowIndex }: GetTableCellParams) => {
    cy.contains('th', columnName)
      .invoke('index')
      .then((index) => {
        cy.get('tr')
          .eq(rowIndex)
          .within((row) => {
            return cy.get('td').eq(index);
          });
      });
  }
);
```

It does find the right table cell. However, since it does so inside a callback, I can't do anything with it - I would like to be able to call chainable methods such as `contains`, `click`, etc. How can I refactor this so the caller has access to this element, being able to call `contains`, `click` and other chainable methods?

I could also use some help on the function readability. It looks like a mess - I guess the problem lies with the nested callbacks...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works with no returns at all.

Cypress uses a command stack, and the last subject on the stack is the value returned.

The problem with `.within()` is it ***reverts*** the subject after it finishes.

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('getTableCell', ({ columnName, rowIndex }: GetTableCellParams) => {

  cy.contains('th', columnName).invoke('index')
    .then(colIndex => {
      cy.get('tr').eq(rowIndex)
        .find('td').eq(colIndex)
    });
  }
)
```

---

To illustrate, try aliasing the `<td>` and follow the `.within()` by getting the alias value

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('getTableCell', ({ columnName, rowIndex }) => {
  cy.contains('th', columnName)
    .invoke('index')
    .then(colIndex => {
      cy.get('tr')
        .eq(rowIndex)
        .within((row) => {
          cy.get('td').eq(colIndex).as('cell')
        })
        cy.get('@cell')   // last command, it's result will be returned
    });
  }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Your command is almost working -- the main issue is that [`.within()` yields the same element it was given.](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/within#Arguments) Instead, we should [use `.find()`.](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/find#Yields)
2. You'll need to yield the *entire* Cypress chain to have the command chainable as you'd like. In this case, after subbing out `.within()` for `.find()`, that means just adding a `return` before the initial `cy.contains()`

```js
Cypress.Commands.add(
  'getTableCell',
  ({ columnName, rowIndex }: GetTableCellParams) => {
    return cy.contains('th', columnName)
      .invoke('index')
      .then((index) => {
        return cy.get('tr')
          .eq(rowIndex)
          .find('td')
          .eq(index);
      });
  }
);
```